# Quicksort in Mips assembler

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips

Im trying to learn some assembler, and right now im trying to get the quicksort algorithm to work. But something is wrong.

Lets say i use this array

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4

it end up like this

1,2,3,4,4,6,6,8,8,9

Have someone an idea where the problem might be?
This is my quicksort code.

```
QuickSort:
    bgt     a1, a2, QuickSortEnd    
    nop

    subu    sp, sp, 16
    sw      ra, 16(sp)
    sw      a0, 12(sp)
    sw      a1, 8(sp)
    sw      a2, 4(sp)   #save a0, a1, a2, ra
    jal Partition       #partition(v, a, b)
    nop 

    subu    sp, sp, 4
    sw      v0, 4(sp)   
    lw      a0, 16(sp)      #a0 = v
    lw      a1, 12(sp)      #a1 = a
    addi    a2, v0, -1      #a2 = k - 1 
    jal QuickSort
    nop

    lw      a0, 16(sp)  #a0 = v
    lw      t0, 4(sp)
    addi    a1, t0, 1   #a1 = k + 1
    lw      a2, 8(sp)   #a2 = b
    jal QuickSort
    nop

    addu sp, sp, 20
    lw ra, 0(sp)    
    nop

QuickSortEnd: jr ra
```

And this is the partition part

```
Partition:
    add t1, a1, a1
    add t1, t1, t1
    add t1, t1, a0      #t2 = pivot
    lw  t2, 0(t1)       #v[a]
    nop
    addi t3, a1, 1      #t3 = lower = a + 1
    addi t4, a2, 0      #t4 = upper = b

Do:
blt t4, t3, PartitionEnd

    W1:
    add     t8, t3, t3
    add     t8, t8, t8
    add     t8, t8, a0      
    lw      t5, 0(t8)       #t5 = v[lower]
    nop
    ble     t5, t2, W12
    nop
    b       W2
    W12:
    ble     t3, t4, W1_Op
    nop
    b       W2
    W1_Op:
    addi    t3, t3, 1
    b       W1

    W2:
    add     t8, t4, t4
    add     t8, t8, t8
    add     t8, t8, a0      
    lw      t5, 0(t8)       #t5 = v[upper]
    nop
    bgt     t5, t2, W22
    nop
    b       f
    W22:
    ble     t3, t4, W2_Op
    nop
    b       f
    W2_Op:
    addi    t4, t4, -1
    b       W2

f:
    bgt     t3, t4, Do
    nop
    add     t8, t3, t3
    add     t8, t8, t8
    add     t8, t8, a0      
    lw      t6, 0(t8)       #temp = v[lower]
    nop

    add     t9, t4, t4
    add     t9, t9, t9
    add     t9, t9, a0      
    lw      t7, 0(t1)       #v[upper]
    nop

    sw      t7, 0(t8)       #v[lower] = v[upper]
    sw      t6, 0(t9)       #v[upper] = temp

    addi    t3, t3, 1
    addi    t4, t4, -1

j Do

PartitionEnd:
    add     t8, t4, t4
    add     t8, t8, t8
    add     t8, t8, a0      
    lw      t2, 0(t8)       #temp = v[upper]
    nop

    add     t9, a1, a1
    add     t9, t9, t9
    add     t9, t9, a0      
    lw      t3, 0(t9)       #v[a]
    nop

    sw      t3, 0(t8)       # v[upper] = v[a]
    sw      t2, 0(t9)       # v[a] = temp

    addi    v0, t4, 0       #return upper(k)
    jr      ra
    nop
```

I call the quicksort function with arguments

```
a0 = address of array to be sortet
a1 = 0
a2 = (number of elements) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your "f" subroutine you called the $t1 register when you meant to call the $t9 register. Simple fix, but next time commenting your code and learning to utilize your registers more efficiently may help. Fewer registers makes it easier to keep track of.